# John the Ripper doesn't crack passwords when I use wordlists

Tags: passwords, hash, john-the-ripper

Title says it all, I can't tell if John is just crashing or "gives up" on cracking the hash. First I start off by creating an md5 hash out of a word I KNOW is on the rockyou.txt wordlist:

```
echo -n 'password' | md5sum > testhash
```

After removing the hyphen at the end of the test hash file:

```
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

Now I attempt to crack the md5 hash using the following John the Ripper command:

```
john --format=raw-md5 --wordlist= /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt testhash
```

I get the output:

```
Loaded 1 password hash (Raw-MD5 [MD5 256/256 AVX2 8*3])
No password hashes left to crack (see FAQ)
```

Then I run:

```
john --show testhash
```

Which outputs:

```
0 password hashes cracked, 2 left
```

Sorry if I'm doing something terribly wrong, but I'm at a loss here. I'm assuming it's something wrong with how my installation of John on Kali Linux is handling the wordlist. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove the space in `--wordlist= /usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt`. You're passing a blank value as the wordlist currently.